# question on derivation in book. integration

Tags: integration

I do not see how the book went from the equation $(1-c^2) u_{\zeta\zeta}=\sin(u)$ to equation (5.2) below it. The books says to multiply both sides by $\frac{du}{d\zeta}$ and "integrate". I do not see it:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a second order differential equation. $c$ is constant. So in expanded form it is simply
$$
   (1-c^2)\frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2} = \sin(u)
$$
And $u$ is function of $\zeta$, i.e. $u(\zeta)$. So when multiplying both sides by $\frac{du}{d\zeta}$ the result is

$$
    (1-c^2)\frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2} \frac{du}{d\zeta} = \sin(u) \frac{du}{d\zeta}
$$
Now, what is the integration done with respect to?  If I just instead integrate w.r.t. $u$ then it becomes
$$
    (1-c^2)\frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2} du = \sin(u) du
$$
Then I now see the RHS $\int \sin(u)\,du = -\cos(u)+c_1$ But how did then the LHS
$\int (1-c^2)\frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2} \,du$ become $\frac{1}{2} (\frac{du}{d\zeta})^2 (1-c^2)$ ? I.e. how is $\int\frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2} \,du =\frac{1}{2} (\frac{du}{d\zeta})^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is integrating with respect to $\zeta$. Note that if you differentiate $-\cos(u)+c_1$ with respect to $\zeta$, then by the chain rule you obtain

$$\sin(u)\frac{du}{d\zeta}$$

Also by the chain rule, if you differentiate $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{du}{d\zeta}\right)^2$ with respect to $\zeta$, you get

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2}\frac{du}{d\zeta}.$$

In other words, $\int \frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2}\frac{du}{d\zeta} d\zeta = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{du}{d\zeta}\right)^2 + c_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how. Let $\frac{du}{d\zeta} = w \implies \frac{ d^2 u }{d\zeta^2}=\frac{dw}{d\zeta}=w' $ so the integral becomes

> $$ \int\frac{d^2u}{d\zeta^2} \,du =  \int w(\zeta) w'(\zeta) \,d\zeta = \frac{1}{2}w^2(\zeta)   .$$
>   Now just substitute $w=\frac{du}{d\zeta}$ and the desired answer follows.

**Note:**

> $$ \int {f(x)}{f'(x)}dx = \frac{f(x)^2}{2} + C. $$

Comment: thanks. I can't up vote you since I do not have enough rep.

Comment: @SteveH: You are welcome. Do not worry.